# Python Popen processes without communicate finish quicker

Tags: python, subprocess, multiprocessing

I'm not entirely sure why but I essentially want to run 2 processes so I use the subprocess Popen function.

```
commands = ['command 1', 'command 2']
for command in commands:
    proc = Popen(command.split(' '))
    proc.communicate()       # line of interest
```

The commands are rendering processes so when they're complete they create an image in a directory. What's strange though is that when I run them with communicate(), essentially in series, they finish in the expected amount of time (time 1 + time 2 roughly).

However, when I run them without communicate(), which should effectively run them in parallel it takes MUCH longer for both of them to finish. Does anyone understand why this behavior might occur and how to remedy it?

Comment: Is it just 2 commands or do you actually have more?  What do your system resources look like when you run this -- e.g. Are you sure you're not hitting swap with memory or something?

Comment: Yeah, it's really just 2 (rendering jobs, so heavily parallel). It isn't maxing out the CPUs nor is it using any swap space. There seems to be more than enough resources for it

Answer (score 0):

To have them run in parallel, you need to instantiate `Popen` multiple times. Your example suggests that you do not communicate with the processes via stdin, stdout or stderr, but via files instead. Assuming this, you can use the `wait` method instead of `communicate`. So the result might look like this:

```
commands = [['command', '1'], ['command', '2']]
processes = [Popen(command) for command in commands]
# they are both running now
returncodes = [process.wait() for process in processes]
# successful if all returncodes are 0
```

If your rendering processes are written in Python as well, have a look at the `multiprocessing` module. It can help parllelize your code using multiple processes avoiding GIL contention.

If you are indeed communicating with your processes, you will need to use a more complex mechanism for multiplexing the IO operations. This is also a place where the `multiprocessing` module can come in handy, but you might be able to implement the communication using `asyncore` or another IO framework as well.